# Как в mongoose проверить длину массива

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Есть схема личной библиотеки для mongoose:

```
{
 name:{type:String}, 
 books:{type:Array(Number), default:[]} 
}
```

Возможно ли составить запрос на выборку только тех библиотек у которых длина books больше 0?

Comment: Можно использовать `$size`, например:`db.collection.find(books:{$size:2})`, но он не принимает диапазон значений, только целое число. Для диапазона, разработчики советуют создать дополнительное поле-счетчик. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/#op._S_size

Comment: Возможно агрегация Вам поможет, но я в ней не силен